# How to crop image based on contents (Python & OpenCV)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

Well currently I'm working on a personal project which is the identification of products in a scanned image taken from a store catalog.

[image: example,]

As you may see in the image there's no lines separation between products, so using `Hough lines` to locate the products won't really solve the problem!

Using `Tesseract` is really amazing to extract the image content, the only problem that I'm facing is finding the image products automatically, I mean not cropping the image manually but I want to detect the products, cropping them with their text description and price and then extract content using OCR.

I have tried many image processing techniques but still nothing (I'm using Python and OpenCV).
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: P.S. You should add a few more details regarding what you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is usually called background removal, or alternatively foreground extraction. In this example, it might actually be relatively easy, as the background is mostly in shades of the same color - my recommendation would be to look at the GrabCut algorithm which is described here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html